# MySQL no añade las claves foraneas

Tags: mysql

Buenas, estoy haciendo una base de datos en MySQL workbench, y resulta que en la tabla ventas y distribución por algún motivo  no me añade las claves foraneas:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Esta es mi consulta SQL:

```
drop database if exists coches_ventas;
create database coches_ventas;
use coches_ventas;

drop table if exists clientes;
drop table if exists ventas;
drop table if exists Coches;
drop table if exists concesionarios;
drop table if exists marco;
drop table if exists marca;
drop table if exists distribucion;

CREATE TABLE clientes (
    dni VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,    
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    apellidos VARCHAR(30),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20)
);


CREATE TABLE concesionarios (
    cifc VARCHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,   
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE coches (
    codcoche INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,   
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    modelo VARCHAR(10)
);


CREATE TABLE marca (
    cifm INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,   
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE marco (
    cifm INT(11),   
    codcoche INT(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifm) REFERENCES marca (cifm),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas (
    cifc INT(11),
    dni VARCHAR(10),
    codcoche INT(11),
    color VARCHAR(10),
    Primary key (cifc, dni, codcoche),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifc) REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
    FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES clientes (dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);


CREATE TABLE distribucion (
    cifc INT(11),   
    codcoche INT(11),
    cantidad INT(11),
    Primary key (cifc, codcoche),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifc)REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);
```

¿Alguien sabe donde esta el error? Un saludo!

Comment: que linea o create reporta el error? y que tendra que ver la etiqueta oracle con esto...

Comment: Me da error en la creacion de la tabla, y de verdad que ya no veo el error, si es la syntax o bien la referencia de las claves.... Y ahora mismo corrijo la etiqueta, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu error podria estar aquí:

```
CREATE TABLE concesionarios (
cifc VARCHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,   
nombre VARCHAR(20),
ciudad VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Tienes `cifc` como `VARCHAR` y en la siguiente tabla lo tienes asi:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas (
cifc INT(11),
dni VARCHAR(10),
codcoche INT(11),
color VARCHAR(10),
Primary key (cifc, dni, codcoche),
FOREIGN KEY (cifc) REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES clientes (dni),
FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);
```

Aquí tienes `cifc` como `INT`

Comment: Efectivamente, era justo eso. Ya se ejecuta sin ningún problema, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes en tu tabla concecionarios cifc como VARCHAR:

```
CREATE TABLE concesionarios (
    cifc VARCHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,   
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20)
    );
```

Y en ventas la tienes como INT:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas (
    cifc INT(11),
    dni VARCHAR(10),
    codcoche INT(11),
    color VARCHAR(10),
    Primary key (cifc, dni, codcoche),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifc) REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
    FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES clientes (dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);
```

Al igual que en distribucion:

```
CREATE TABLE distribucion (
    cifc INT(11),   
    codcoche INT(11),
    cantidad INT(11),
    Primary key (cifc, codcoche),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifc)REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);
```

Tendrías que cambiar en tu tabla de concesionarios a INT:

```
CREATE TABLE concesionarios (
    cifc INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,   
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20)
    );
```

O si tu campo cifc podrá recibir valores alfanuméricos, cambia en tus tablas distribucion y ventas a VARCHAR:

```
CREATE TABLE distribucion (
    cifc VARCHAR(11),   
    codcoche INT(11),
    cantidad INT(11),
    Primary key (cifc, codcoche),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifc)REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas (
    cifc VARCHAR(11),
    dni VARCHAR(10),
    codcoche INT(11),
    color VARCHAR(10),
    Primary key (cifc, dni, codcoche),
    FOREIGN KEY (cifc) REFERENCES concesionarios (cifc),
    FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES clientes (dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (codcoche) REFERENCES coches (codcoche)
);
```